# Lettrine loversize causes Parallel text to be bottom aligned

Tags: xetex, lettrine, parallel, parallel-texts

For some reason, using a `lettrine` with the optional `loversize` argument at the start of a `ParallelLText` or `ParallelRText` in a `p`-type `Parallel` environment causes the parallel text to be bottom-aligned on the page when the document is compiled with XeLaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text generation

\begin{document}
    \begin{Parallel}[p]\textwidth\textwidth
        \ParallelLText{\lettrine[loversize=0.2]{1}{}\ \lipsum[5]}
        \ParallelRText{\lettrine[loversize=0.2]{1}{}\ \lipsum[5]}
    \end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

I've only included one page of the output. The other page is the same.

[image: MWE output; the text is aligned to the bottom of the page instead of the top]

This doesn't happen if the `loversize` parameter is omitted from the `lettrine` calls. How can I avoid this alignment issue while still adjusting the size of my lettrine? This issue does not seem to happen if I compile using plain LaTeX.

Comment: It's most likely a bug in XeTeX, you should report it to the developers here : [Bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/)